# Syslog has weird entry and after that my server died

Tags: linux

Following are my syslog entries. There is an entry for NOV 9.After that I could not ssh into that machine even.Is that related ?

```
  Oct 26 11:35:50 prod-slavemongo2 dhclient: bound to 20.0.1.47 -- renewal in 1521 seconds.
    Oct 26 12:01:11 prod-slavemongo2 dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 20.0.1.47 on eth0 to 20.0.1.1 port 67 (xid=0x77f07311)
    Oct 26 12:01:11 prod-slavemongo2 dhclient: DHCPACK of 20.0.1.47 from 20.0.1.1
    Oct 26 12:01:11 prod-slavemongo2 dhclient: bound to 20.0.1.47 -- renewal in 1529 seconds.
    Oct 26 12:17:01 prod-slavemongo2 CRON[9259]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
    Oct 26 12:41:24 prod-slavemongo2 nrpe[9363]: Connection has taken too long to establish. Exiting...
    Oct 26 12:53:09 prod-slavemongo2 dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 20.0.1.47 on eth0 to 20.0.1.1 port 67 (xid=0x77f07311)
    Oct 26 12:53:39 prod-slavemongo2 nrpe[9366]: Connection has taken too long to establish. Exiting...
    Oct 26 13:06:38 prod-slavemongo2 nrpe[9369]: Connection has taken too long to establish. Exiting...
    Oct 26 13:16:59 prod-slavemongo2 dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 20.0.1.47 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x77f07311)
    **Nov  9 08:17:01 prod-slavemongo2 CRON[9372]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)**
    Oct 26 13:32:28 prod-slavemongo2 nrpe[9372]: Connection has taken too long to establish. Exiting...
    Oct 26 14:07:42 prod-slavemongo2 dhclient: DHCPACK of 20.0.1.47 from 20.0.1.1
    Oct 26 14:25:36 prod-slavemongo2 nrpe[9377]: Connection has taken too long to establish. Exiting...
    Oct 26 15:14:26 prod-slavemongo2 nrpe[9383]: Connection has taken too long to establish. Exiting...
```

Comment: If you are speaking about `    **Nov  9 08:17:01 prod-slavemongo2 CRON[9372]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)**` - that is just report, that `etc/cron.hourly` was run. There is nothing related to server being unreachable here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am curious why it published a wrong date.